# Kill process that keeps restarting itself

Tags: mac-osx, process, jenkins

I need some advice on how to completely kill the Jenkins process. It keeps restarting itself. On Mac OSX.

```
$ps -eaf
216  1143     1   0   0:01.65 ??         0:04.03 /usr/bin/java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
```

try to kill the process...

```
kill 1143
```

the process still exists under a different pid

```
$ps -eaf
216  1175     1   0   0:00.16 ??         0:01.44 /usr/bin/java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
```

the parent process is launchd. What do I do?

```
0     1     0   0   0:06.09 ??         0:06.19 /sbin/launchd
```

Answer (score 27):

from the command line:

```
launchctl list
```

find the exact name of the process/app you don't want coming back.
Then

```
launchctl remove <name_from_list_command>
```

hope this helps

Comment: it didnt help sorry. They are still popping up

Comment: @SamuelThompson since you are not the owner of the original question, and your comment being about 5+ years late, I am assuming your situation is not the same as the original poster. There are more than one way to make applications persistent. There might be another totally irrelevant named process, which will be watching for this process and starting it up when it ceases to exist. Since 2013, Mas OSX has changed so many versions and me, not following it, the mechanism might have been changed as well. If I were you, I'd ask a new question.